# Change AVI creation date with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

As far as I can tell the following ffmpeg command should copy all existing metadata in the input file to the output file and modify the specified field in the output file:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20130502_220104.avi -metadata creation_time="2013-05-02 22:01:04" -codec copy VID_20130502_220104-2.avi
```

Instead, it seems to strip all metadata from the output file. Here is the output of a few commands. I am going nuts. I think this should work, but why is it not?

Command to edit the creation time:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20130502_220104.avi -metadata creation_time="2013-05-02 22:01:04" -codec copy VID_20130502_220104-2.avi

ffmpeg version 3.1.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'VID_20130502_220104.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : 
    maker           : NIKON
    model           : COOLPIX S4300
    creation_time   : 2011-01-01 00:00:00
  Duration: 00:01:30.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32135 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 31782 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
[avi @ 000000000032ad40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, avi, to 'VID_20130502_220104-2.avi':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-05-02 22:01:04
    maker           : NIKON
    model           : COOLPIX S4300
    ISFT            : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, q=2-31, 31782 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, 352 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  891 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=  116171kB time=00:00:29.69 bitrate=32043.1kbits/s speed=59.4x    
frame= 1739 fps=1739 q=-1.0 size=  227191kB time=00:00:57.96 bitrate=32107.5kbits/s speed=  58x    
frame= 2609 fps=1739 q=-1.0 size=  340940kB time=00:01:26.96 bitrate=32115.9kbits/s speed=  58x    
frame= 2715 fps=1734 q=-1.0 Lsize=  355018kB time=00:01:30.49 bitrate=32136.3kbits/s speed=57.8x    
video:350984kB audio:3897kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.038597%
```

Command to inspect the output file metadata with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20130502_220104-2.avi

ffmpeg version 3.1.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'VID_20130502_220104-2.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:01:30.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32136 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 31782 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Command to inspect the input file metadata with exiftool:

```
exiftool.exe VID_20130502_220104.avi

ExifTool Version Number         : 10.30
File Name                       : VID_20130502_220104.avi
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 347 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:05:13 16:33:52-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:11:10 23:08:25-05:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2015:11:10 23:08:25-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : AVI
File Type Extension             : avi
MIME Type                       : video/x-msvideo
Frame Rate                      : 30
Max Data Rate                   : 488.3 kB/s
Frame Count                     : 2715
Stream Count                    : 2
Stream Type                     : Video
Video Codec                     : mjpg
Video Frame Rate                : 30
Video Frame Count               : 2715
Quality                         : 10000
Sample Size                     : Variable
Image Width                     : 1280
Image Height                    : 720
Planes                          : 1
Bit Depth                       : 24
Compression                     : MJPG
Image Length                    : 2764800
Pixels Per Meter X              : 0
Pixels Per Meter Y              : 0
Num Colors                      : Use BitDepth
Num Important Colors            : All
Audio Codec                     : 
Audio Sample Rate               : 22050
Audio Sample Count              : 1995256
Encoding                        : Microsoft PCM
Num Channels                    : 1
Sample Rate                     : 22050
Avg Bytes Per Sec               : 44100
Bits Per Sample                 : 16
Maker Note Type                 : NIKON
Maker Note Version              : 0.1.0.0
Make                            : NIKON
Model                           : COOLPIX S4300
Software                        : V1.0
Equipment                       : NIKON DIGITAL CAMERA
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Exposure Time                   : 1/15
F Number                        : 3.5
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 3.2
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Focal Length                    : 4.6 mm
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Date/Time Original              : 2011:01:01 00:00:00
Create Date                     : 2011:01:01 00:00:00
Focus Mode                      : AF-S
Digital Zoom                    : 1
Color Mode                      : COLOR
Sharpness                       : AUTO
White Balance                   : NORMAL
Noise Reduction                 : OFF
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 3082 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Aperture                        : 3.5
Duration                        : 0:01:30
Image Size                      : 1280x720
Megapixels                      : 0.922
Shutter Speed                   : 1/15
Focal Length                    : 4.6 mm
```

Command to inspect the output file metadata with exiftool:

```
exiftool.exe VID_20130502_220104-2.avi

ExifTool Version Number         : 10.30
File Name                       : VID_20130502_220104-2.avi
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 347 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:11:01 00:17:38-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:11:01 00:17:36-04:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2016:11:01 00:15:18-04:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : AVI
File Type Extension             : avi
MIME Type                       : video/x-msvideo
Frame Rate                      : 30
Max Data Rate                   : 3923 kB/s
Frame Count                     : 2715
Stream Count                    : 2
Stream Type                     : Video
Video Codec                     : MJPG
Video Frame Rate                : 30
Video Frame Count               : 2715
Quality                         : Default
Sample Size                     : Variable
Image Width                     : 1280
Image Height                    : 720
Planes                          : 1
Bit Depth                       : 24
Compression                     : MJPG
Image Length                    : 2764800
Pixels Per Meter X              : 0
Pixels Per Meter Y              : 0
Num Colors                      : Use BitDepth
Num Important Colors            : All
Audio Codec                     : .
Audio Sample Rate               : 22050
Audio Sample Count              : 1995256
Encoding                        : Microsoft PCM
Num Channels                    : 1
Sample Rate                     : 22050
Avg Bytes Per Sec               : 44100
Bits Per Sample                 : 16
Software                        : Lavf57.41.100
Duration                        : 0:01:30
Image Size                      : 1280x720
Megapixels                      : 0.922
```

Comment: The metadata option sets a tag and does not affect the file creation/mod time. You need a utility like [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)) for that.

Comment: @Mulvya Obviously. If I wanted to change file attributes I wouldn't use ffmpeg. "creation_time" is a ffmpeg metadata key. I wouldn't expect it to change file attributes. From my pasted logs you can clearly see that ffmpeg reads a "creation_time" in the input file and exiftool reads a "Date/Time Original" and "Create Date" which are all "2011:01:01 00:00:00" which is different from all the file attribute dates. The problem is that in the output file neither ffmpeg or exiftool sees those metadata anymore, it's gone. ffmpeg seems to have striped the metadata from the output file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `creation_time` works for MOV/MP4/MKV files.

For AVI, the syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i old.avi -metadata ICRD="2013-05-02 22:01:04" -c copy new.avi
```

Usually, to expressly ask ffmpeg to retain all metadata, you would add `-map_metadata 0` but with AVIs, ffmpeg hasn't implemented many of the RIFF tags, especially the vendor-proprietary ones, so I don't know if all will get copied over.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today. Thanks. This page might be of use to anyone else reviewing this question: https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata